# Can't launch Steam games after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, games, steam

I upgraded Ubuntu yesterday from 18.04 to 20.04 and now Steam games aren't launching anymore. When I click on play, Steam either says it's running and then it looks like the game was stopped (there is no game window opening) or it just says that the game is running. I tried to delete and reinstall games, and I tried to validate the game files.

Comment: Are you logged into a wayland session or Xorg? Logout and check on the login screen (cog) to make sure you are using Ubuntu on Xorg.

Comment: Did you visit the Steam support site and see what they have to say?

Comment: @popey I use xfce and dont have the possibility to choose Xorg. I used xfce already before updating is it neccesary to use Xorg?